# Cordova Emulate Android finds no Gradle or installed Android Studio, even though its there

Tags: android, angular, cordova, gradle

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxW87.png)

I know that the app itself should work, I just had to work on a different part of the project and when I came back to it, this error message suddenly popped up. No solution worked for me, so I am asking here.

If the picture above cant be seen, here is the message again:

*Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ibs\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio*

Comment: when you open the project in the android studio? .So that it will ask to update your Gradle then update it

Comment: its not asking for an update though, it's saying that it can't find it at all? or do i understand that wrong?

Comment: and is the location included in your path?

Comment: The SDK root is undefined and the android home is set to the sdk repo

Comment: but you can see that in the information i provided above; or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the environmental variable. Deleting it and creating it anew, like in the Gradle documentation solved it for me.